# Messagebox (OK/Cancel) appears twice on Cancel

Tags: vba, if-statement, msgbox

The following code checks if a file starts with te right name, after that in checks what the user wants. Most of the code works fine but if the users presses "Cancel", the messagebox re-appears.

```
Sub CheckBronbestand()
If Not Left(Dir(frmUpdate.txtOud), 5) = "Ap10" Then
    result = MsgBox("Message line 1." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Message line 2", vbOKCancel + vbQuestion, "Onjuist bestand")
    If result = vbOK Then
        frmUpdate.lblBron.Caption = Left(Dir(frmUpdate.txtOud), InStr(Dir(frmUpdate.txtOud), ".") - 1)
        Exit Sub
    ElseIf result = vbCancel Then
        frmUpdate.txtOud.Text = ""
        Exit Sub
    End If
Else
    frmUpdate.lblBron.Caption = Left(Dir(frmUpdate.txtOud), InStr(Dir(frmUpdate.txtOud), ".") - 1)
End If

End Sub
```

I can't see what the problem is, What can I do?

Comment: How is the Sub `CheckBronbestand` called (what triggers it?) Likely, it's not the MessageBox that reappears but the whole routine is called a second time. You should check with the debugger.

Comment: The sub is called by a change event of the textbox (txtOud) 
>> Private Sub txtOud_Change()

Comment: You are changing the text in the box so it is triggering the routine to run again, disable event handling and re-enable before exiting

Answer (score 0):

Thx for your answers, it put me on the right track

Just above the code I added:

```
If frmUpdate.txtOud = "" Then
Exit Sub 
End If
```

Comment: In your change event you could just add `Application.EnableEvents = False` before calling the procedure, and change it back to True afterwards (very important that bit - it doesn't happen automatically when the code ends).  Having said that.... not sure if it works on user forms, does on worksheets.  Don't think I've ever used it elsewhere, but the help file does state "events are enabled for the specified object." and a form is an object.